# Custom UI for watson assistant

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson

I have developed a bot using Watson assistant, instead of using the IBM provided webchat UI, I want to use my custom chat widget for the bot. I have the chat widget code and I want to know how to provide communication of Watson assistant into my custom chat widget using nodejs?

Comment: I am able to use watson nodejs api and run the file locally, but not able to figure out how to connect communication between the chat widget and the nodejs api of the watson.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the sdk or api to communicate with the Watson assistant service.
You can find the node sdk here:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/assistant
If you get any specific errors we are happy to help.

Comment: I know how to use nodejs api, but not able to figure out how to connect the nodejs api with my chat widget which is in js.